# How to get docker architecture, like amd64, arm32v7, in alpine linux?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

As the official docker alpine repository got multi-architecture support, How can I get the architecture name within the base image, especially in Dockerfile?

https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64

Only getting the system is 32bit or 64bit is not good enough. I prefer the result to be the same as the docker architectures, like arm32v7, arm64v8, amd64, etc.

My goal is to bulid a nodejs docker image. For amd64, most dependences are available directly, while for some other architectures, they need to be compiled from source, in which case extra deps like python, gcc/g++ are required. I wish my script in dockerfile can figure it out and only install these extra deps only when necessary.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58222507/3206908 . In short: `apk --print-arch`

Answer (score 9):

Image recipes for different architectures have their own Dockerfiles, so it's just a matter of picking the right one to work with (hope I got your question right).

There are available Node images for Alpine targeting various architectures, for example:

`docker pull ppc64le/node:8-alpine`

Is the Node.js 8.12.0 image for PPC64LE on Alpine 3.8.

**Edit after clarification:**

For a multiarch Dockerfile that builds differently depending on the target architecture, you could resolve arch name on runtime, by checking the result of `uname -m` and using shell conditionals, for example:

```
RUN /bin/ash -c 'set -ex && \
    ARCH=`uname -m` && \
    if [ "$ARCH" == "x86_64" ]; then \
       echo "x86_64" && \
       apk add some-package; \
    else \
       echo "unknown arch" && \
       apk add some-other-package; \
    fi'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know there are separated architectures for public repos. In my use case, I have amd64/node:8 for amd64 and arm32v7/node:8-slim for arm32v7. The problem is at the `slim` mark. To install some packages like sqlite. the amd64 image works fine because the package is prebuilt. But for arm32v7, it has to compile from source so buildtools are required.  I do not prefer several dockerfiles for architectures, I believe doing some conditional statements in dockerfile work better.

Comment: @aGuegu Thanks for the explanation, it's much clearer now. I've updated my answer - please check if it fits your needs.

Comment: so your approach is by `uname -m`, it could work. However, I prefer something more `dockerized`: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64

Comment: This resulted in a syntax error for me with Bash. That said, I am now using the `TARGETPLATFORM` argument instead: https://nielscautaerts.xyz/making-dockerfiles-architecture-independent.html