# Is it possible to get the architecture of the docker engine in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I know it's possible to get the architecture of the Docker engine simply by running this command :

```
root@minus:~# docker info | grep Architecture
Architecture: armv7l
```

I have also tested it on other architecture and it is working well (`aarch64` on arm64 and `x86_64` for my Intel server).

My question is is there a special variable (usable like an argument) with the architecture available inside a Dockerfile. I know it possible to use an `ARG` for that but that mean that it has to be set by the caller, I would like to have something more automatic.

I would use it to automatically download the right image for the architecture. I've searched quite a lot and did not found anything and I'd be happy if there is a way ;).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought the intent with Docker's architecture structure would be that you would build different docker images for different architectures and then push different images for distribution. If you really wanted to handle this in a dockerfile you could likely have the dockerfile run a script where you check for the OS architecture yourself.

Comment: Ok, I see your point, I could use multi-stage build : the first build with alpine can detect the arch simply by running a `lscpu` or anything else and prepare for the second build. Did not thought of that, will try right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

If you build using BuildKit, there are some predefined ARGs you can use:

> - TARGETPLATFORM - platform of the build result. Eg linux/amd64, linux/arm/v7, windows/amd64.
> - TARGETOS - OS component of TARGETPLATFORM
> - TARGETARCH - architecture component of TARGETPLATFORM
> - TARGETVARIANT - variant component of TARGETPLATFORM
> - BUILDPLATFORM - platform of the node performing the build.
> - BUILDOS - OS component of BUILDPLATFORM
> - BUILDARCH - OS component of BUILDPLATFORM
> - BUILDVARIANT - OS component of BUILDPLATFORM

These are documented in "Automatic platform ARGs in the global scope" in the [builder documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

To use BuildKit, you can enable it within your shell with a variable:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
```

And then build using `docker build` (support for BuildKit using docker-compose is being worked on, likely in the next release).

Comment: BuildKit support in docker-compose was just released: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.25.0

Answer (score 17):

There are examples of conditional code execution based on architecture in some of the official Docker images. The `golang` Dockerfiles, for example, use the package manager to report architecture and then a `case` to conditionally run statements, all in a single chain of commands from a `RUN`. From [golang 1.13:alpine](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/4fa4888b25307c734ed4bbda6ce68549b7d9dbdc/1.13/alpine3.10/Dockerfile#L33):

```sh
    RUN ...
        apkArch="$(apk --print-arch)"; \
        case "$apkArch" in \
            armhf) export GOARM='6' ;; \
            x86) export GO386='387' ;; \
        esac; \
        ...
```

In the [Debian releases](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/4fa4888b25307c734ed4bbda6ce68549b7d9dbdc/1.13/buster/Dockerfile#L17), `dpkg` is used instead of `apk`:

```sh
        dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"; \
```